# GWT /smartGWT change Skin elements

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, skin

For example I want to change the :

C:\Users\media\workspace\TESTPROJECT\war\com.media.project.medistart\sc\skins\Enterprise\images\edges

I open them in Paint and draw new one and overwrite the existing.

when i run my application nothing has changed... 
Someone know how i change the files in the .jar maybe it would work

Comment: Are you running your application in Eclipse or in External web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the file stored under war folder of your project.

**Clear the browser cache first (Ctrl+Shift+Delete)** and run the application.

Here is the structure of war where images are stored one for each skin or theme

```
war
|__WEB-INF
|__testproject
   |__sc
      |__skins
         |__Enterprise
            |__Images
               |__edges
                  |__edge_B.png
```